# Send email with Sendgrid in Django

Tags: python, django, sendgrid

I'm trying to send emails from a Django app using Sendgrid. I've tried many configurations, but I still doesn't get any email on my **Gmail** account. You can see my configurations bellow:

**settings.py:**

```
SEND_GRID_API_KEY = 'APIGENERATEDONSENDGRID'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mySENDGRIDusername'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myEMAILpassword' #sendgrid email
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'MYEMAIL' #sendgrig email
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import get_template


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def contact(request):

    success = False
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        message = request.POST.get("message")

        subject = 'Contact from MYSITE'

        from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
        to_email = [settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL]

        message = 'Name: {0}\nEmail:{1}\n{2}'.format(name, email, message)

        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True)

        success = True 
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'success': success
    }
    return render(request, 'contact.html',context)
```

Do you guys know what could be happening? I can get the email locally and I can see it in the terminal, but no email can be sent at all.

Comment: Did you change your email console backend to smtp backend ?

Comment: Yes, I did!I read in the docs that it's actually a default settings, but even when I change it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check in `spam` as well. Also are you trying to setup sending email behalf of your gmail ?

Comment: Yeah. I also checked spam, nothing there.
I tried to change the email client, tried to use outlook, but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 13):

I struggled a bit when trying to set up the sendgrid with Django using SMTP. What worked for me is the following:

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # this is exactly the value 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'sendgrid-api-key' # this is your API key
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your-email@example.com' # this is the sendgrid email
```

I used this configuration, and it worked properly, and I strongly suggest using environment variables to fill `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` and `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`, so the code will be as follows:

```
import os # this should be at the top of the file

# ...

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD", "")
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.getenv("DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL", "")
```

Then, when sending an email I used the following code:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('This is the title of the email',
          'This is the message you want to send',
          settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
          [
              settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, # add more emails to this list of you want to
          ]
)
```

Comment: so, don't u need SEND_GRID_API_KEY anymore with the configuration above?

Comment: @DaviWesley, you don't need that environment variable, but you should use this value in `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD`.

Comment: but what is the value for EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD my password in sendgrid or the api key?

Comment: `EMAIL_HOST_USER` is exactly `'apikey'` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` is your sendgrid api key. Is this clear?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these to right bellow the your declaration in settings

```
SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG=False

SENDGRID_ECHO_TO_STDOUT=False
```

Answer (score 0):

DO this settings on your settings.py file

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'sendgrid_backend.SendgridBackend'
SENDGRID_SANDBOX_MODE_IN_DEBUG = False
FROM_EMAIL = 'youremail@gmail.com' # replace with your address
SENDGRID_API_KEY = os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
```

dont use debug true if you run this on your local server.

Comment: and open sendgrid webpage and edit your api key to allowed mail services, and click on restricted access.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, I think the SendGrid guide might be missing the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` which seems necessary if you haven't set it up on their website.